# Can't terminate a sudo process created with python, in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: python, ubuntu, subprocess, sudo, ubuntu-15.10

I just updated to Ubuntu 15.10 and suddenly in Python 2.7 I am not able to **terminate** a process I created when being **root**. 
For example, this doesn't terminate tcpdump:

```
import subprocess, shlex, time
tcpdump_command = "sudo tcpdump -w example.pcap -i eth0 -n icmp"
tcpdump_process = subprocess.Popen(
                                shlex.split(tcpdump_command),
                                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
time.sleep(1)
tcpdump_process.terminate()
tcpdump_out, tcpdump_err = tcpdump_process.communicate()
```

What happened? It works on previous versions.

Comment: If you run this while being root, why do you need to call sudo? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Ok, good point.  Without `sudo` it seems to work. But why did it work on all previous versions?

Comment: I don't know why, the most probable scenario is that when you upgraded to 15.10 some configuration about your sudoer or the priviliges related to it or its group changed. Maybe you're running your python without root priviliges and it can't kill elevated shell (cause sudo)

Comment: It shows the same behaviour when running that code while being the root user and while being a regular user + sudo. Well, I'm glad it was just that. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**TL;DR**: `sudo` does not forward signals sent by a process in the command's process group [since 28 May 2014 commit](https://www.sudo.ws/repos/sudo/rev/7ffa2eefd3c0) released in `sudo 1.8.11` -- the python process (sudo's parent) and the tcpdump process (grandchild) are in the same process group by default and therefore `sudo` does not forward `SIGTERM` signal sent by `.terminate()` to the `tcpdump` process.

---

> It shows the same behaviour when running that code while being the root user and while being a regular user + sudo

Running as a regular user raises `OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted` exception on `.terminate()` (as expected).

Running as `root` reproduces the issue: `sudo` and `tcpdump` processes are not killed on `.terminate()` and the code is stuck on `.communicate()` on Ubuntu 15.10.

The same code kills both processes on Ubuntu 12.04.

`tcpdump_process` name is misleading because the variable refers to the `sudo` process (the child process), not `tcpdump` (grandchild):

```
python
└─ sudo tcpdump -w example.pcap -i eth0 -n icmp
   └─ tcpdump -w example.pcap -i eth0 -n icmp
```

As [@Mr.E pointed out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34337840/cant-terminate-a-process-created-with-python-in-ubuntu-15-10#comment56417413_34337840), you don't need `sudo` here: you're root already (though you shouldn't be -- you can [sniff the network without root](https://askubuntu.com/q/74059/3712)). If you drop `sudo`; `.terminate()` works.

In general, `.terminate()` does not kill the whole process tree recursively and therefore it is expected that a grandchild process survives. Though `sudo` is a special case, [from sudo(8) man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man8/sudo.8.html):

> When the command is run as a child of the `sudo` process, `sudo` will
>   ***relay signals*** it receives to the command.<sup>emphasis is mine</sup>

i.e., `sudo` should relay `SIGTERM` to `tcpdump` and [`tcpdump` should stop capturing packets on `SIGTERM`, from tcpdump(8) man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man8/tcpdump.8.html):

> Tcpdump will, ..., continue  capturing  packets until  it is
>   interrupted by a SIGINT signal (generated, for example, by typing your
>   interrupt character,  typically  control-C)  or  a  SIGTERM signal 
>   (typically generated with the kill(1) command);

i.e., **the expected behavior is**: `tcpdump_process.terminate()` sends SIGTERM to `sudo` which relays the signal to `tcpdump` which should stop capturing and both processes exit and `.communicate()` returns `tcpdump`'s stderr output to the python script.

Note: in principle the command may be run without creating a child process, [from the same sudo(8) man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man8/sudo.8.html):

> As a special case, if the policy plugin does not define a close
>   function and no pty is required, `sudo` will execute the command
>   directly instead of calling fork(2) first

and therefore `.terminate()` may send SIGTERM to the `tcpdump` process directly -- though it is not the explanation: `sudo tcpdump` creates two processes on both Ubuntu 12.04 and 15.10 in my tests.

If I run `sudo tcpdump -w example.pcap -i eth0 -n icmp` in the shell then `kill -SIGTERM` terminates both processes. It does not look like Python issue (Python 2.7.3 (used on Ubuntu 12.04) behaves the same on Ubuntu 15.10. Python 3 also fails here).

It is related to process groups ([job control](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man4/termios.4?&manpath=OpenBSD-current&sec=4&query=termios)): passing `preexec_fn=os.setpgrp` to `subprocess.Popen()` so that `sudo` will be in a new process group (job) where it is the leader as in the shell makes `tcpdump_process.terminate()` work in this case.

> What happened? It works on previous versions.

The explanation is in [the sudo's source code](https://www.sudo.ws/repos/sudo/rev/7ffa2eefd3c0):

> ***Do not forward signals sent by a process in the command's process
>   group***, do not forward it as we don't want the child to indirectly kill
>   itself.  For example, this can happen with some versions of reboot
>   that call kill(-1, SIGTERM) to kill all other processes.<sup>emphasis is mine</sup>

`preexec_fn=os.setpgrp` changes `sudo`'s process group. `sudo`'s descendants such as `tcpdump` process inherit the group. `python` and `tcpdump` are no longer in the same process group and therefore the signal sent by `.terminate()` is relayed by `sudo` to `tcpdump` and it exits.

Ubuntu 15.04 uses `Sudo version 1.8.9p5` where the code from the question works as is.

Ubuntu 15.10 uses `Sudo version 1.8.12` that contains [the commit](https://www.sudo.ws/repos/sudo/rev/7ffa2eefd3c0).

[sudo(8) man page in wily (15.10)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man8/sudo.8.html) still talks only about the child process itself -- no mention of the process group:

> As a special case, sudo will not relay signals that were sent by the 
>   command it is running.

It should be instead:

> As a special case, sudo will not relay signals that were sent by a process in the process group of the command  it is running.

You could open a documentation issue on [Ubuntu's bug tracker](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) and/or on [the upstream bug tracker](https://www.sudo.ws/).

Comment: This is especially counter-intuitive as one can still interrupt (SIGINT) a sudo command running in a terminal using CTRL+C. Though this is because the signal is not sent by the process controlling the terminal master side, but instead by the kernel itself. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/251713/257800