# Bash 'swallowing' sub-shell children process when executing a single command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, subshell

Bumped into an unexpected `bash`/`sh` behavior and I wonder someone can explain the rationale behind it, and provide a solution to the question below.

In an interactive `bash` shell session, I execute:

`$ bash -c 'sleep 10 && echo'`

With `ps` on Linux it looks like this:

`\_ -bash
   \_ bash -c sleep 10 && echo
     \_ sleep 10`

The process tree is what I would expect:

- My interactive bash shell process (`$`)
- A children shell process (`bash -c ...`)
- a sleep children process

However, if the *command* portion of my `bash -c` is a **single** command, e.g.:

`$ bash -c 'sleep 10'`

Then the middle sub-shell is swallowed, and my interactive terminal session executes sleep "directly" as children process.
The process tree looks like this:

`\_ -bash
   \_ sleep 10`

So from process tree perspective, these two produce the same result:

- `$ bash -c 'sleep 10'`
- `$ sleep 10`

What is going on here?

Now to my question: is there a way to force the intermediate shell, regardless of the complexity of the expression passed to `bash -c ...`?

(I could append something like `; echo;` to my actual command and that "works", but I'd rather not. Is there a more proper way to force the intermediate process into existence?)

(edit: typo in `ps` output; removed `sh` tag as suggested in comments; one more typo)

Comment: Why would you *not* want this optimization when it's possible?

Comment: Mostly ensure consistent behavior when dealing with child processes in an environment where users can pass in arbitrary commands. I am not sure bypassing this optimization is my solution (the actual problem I'm having has to deal with a change of sudo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34376188). But this behavior was interesting and I wanted to learn more about it.

Comment: Great question.  Did you mean to say `\_ bash -c sleep 10 && echo` instead of `\_ bash -c sleep 10 && sleep 10` on line 2 of your first ps tree?

Comment: @codeforester indeed, thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's actually a comment [in the bash source](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/execute_cmd.c?h=bash-4.4#n1595) that describes much of the rationale for this feature:

```c
/* If this is a simple command, tell execute_disk_command that it
   might be able to get away without forking and simply exec.
   This means things like ( sleep 10 ) will only cause one fork.
   If we're timing the command or inverting its return value, however,
   we cannot do this optimization. */
if ((user_subshell || user_coproc) && (tcom->type == cm_simple || tcom->type == cm_subshell) &&
    ((tcom->flags & CMD_TIME_PIPELINE) == 0) &&
    ((tcom->flags & CMD_INVERT_RETURN) == 0))
  {
    tcom->flags |= CMD_NO_FORK;
    if (tcom->type == cm_simple)
      tcom->value.Simple->flags |= CMD_NO_FORK;
  }
```

In the `bash -c '...'` case, the `CMD_NO_FORK` flag is set when determined by  the [`should_suppress_fork` function](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/evalstring.c?h=bash-4.4#n100) in `builtins/evalstring.c`.

It is **always** to your benefit to let the shell do this. It only happens when:

- Input is from a hardcoded string, and the shell is at the last command in that string.
- There are no further commands, traps, hooks, etc. to be run after the command is complete.
- The exit status does not need to be inverted or otherwise modified.
- No redirections need to be backed out.

This saves memory, causes the startup time of the process to be slightly faster (since it doesn't need to be `fork`ed), and ensures that signals delivered to your PID go direct to the process you're running, making it possible for the parent of `sh -c 'sleep 10'` to determine exactly which signal killed `sleep`, should it in fact be killed by a signal.

However, if for some reason you want to inhibit it, you need but set a trap -- any trap will do:

```
# run the noop command (:) at exit
bash -c 'trap : EXIT; sleep 10'
```

Comment: I can't tell from the source, but it seems to me Bash only does that if there is only one command on the whole `-c` command line. So something like `bash -c ":; sleep 10"` keeps the shell running even after it starts the sleep.

Comment: @ilkkachu, my intuitive expectation is that that's likely to vary by version -- 3.2 is going to be prior to the late-2014 implementation of `should_suppress_fork`, f/e. And even if it's the case today, I wouldn't expect it to still be true in future releases (which hopefully would resolve the missing opportunity for optimization) -- whereas a trap will *always* necessitate keeping the shell running.

Comment: Seems to act similarly in both 3.2 and 4.4.

Comment: *nod*. Useful to know for current behavior, but I'm still skeptical that it's trustworthy going forward. If one *can* make a script run that much faster (granted, only a few ms in typical cases, but still) by having an implicit `exec` for its last command, why would Chet ever turn down that patch if someone were to write it?

Comment: Thank you. In case you are wondering why I want to force that middle shell to exist in all cases, then answer is related to the change in `sudo` mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34376188. A kill to sudo used to be forwarded to its children, but it's no longer the case, so I am trying to spawn my processes in a different process group.