# Why does std::system return a different exit status when I redirect the output to a file?

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, redhat, exit-code

I am trying to check the exit status of a process executed via `std::system` in C++ and I found that when a process aborts I end up with a different exit status depending on whether I redirect STDOUT to a file or not.

Here is an example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

void parse_status(int status)
{
    if (WIFEXITED(status))
    {
        // Process completed successfully, translate the status to the exit code of the process
        cout << "Process completed with status " << WEXITSTATUS(status) << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        // An error has occurred
        std::ostringstream error;

        if (WIFSIGNALED(status))
        {
            // Process was killed
            status = WTERMSIG(status);
            error << "Process killed (signal " << status << ")";
        }
        else if (WIFSTOPPED(status))
        {
            // Process was stopped
            status = WSTOPSIG(status);
            error << "Process stopped (signal " << status << ")";
        }
        else
        {
            // Process returned an unknown status
            error << "Process returned an unexpected status (0x" << std::hex << status << ")";
        }

        cerr << error.str() << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int status1 = system("my_subprocess");
    int status2 = system("my_subprocess >out.txt");

    parse_status(status1);
    parse_status(status2);
}
```

And the code for `my_subprocess` which intentionally aborts is shown here:

```cpp
int main()
{
    throw;
}
```

The output I get from running the test program is:

```
terminate called without an active exception
terminate called without an active exception
sh: line 1:  2127 Aborted                 (core dumped) my_subprocess > out.txt
Process killed (signal 6)
Process completed with status 134
```

As you can see, simply redirecting STDOUT drastically altered the returned status code from the process.

What is happening here and why does the exit code change?

Comment: you're supposed to use `WIFEXITED` etc. to decode the return value.

Comment: Note that you don't get the ouput of `sh` detecting the error for the non-redirect case - I'm pretty sure it does an `exec` when simple.

Comment: q.v. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system

Comment: @o11c you are right. I have updated the question to include (what I believe is correct) processing of the exit status. It still gives different results.

Comment: See the comments on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44576773/bash-swallowing-sub-shell-children-process-when-executing-a-single-command

Comment: @o11c I don't fully understand why the solution to that other question worked, but it worked lol. Thank you!